# How do I prepend/append this div as the last child of all the children as opposed to the first?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a view that has renders HTML that looks like this :

[image]

What is happening now is when the user adds a new comment, it is now added to the top of that list, i.e. the `div.social-comment` that is highlighted. However, I want it to be added after the last in the list, not as the first. How do I do that?

This is what the `create.js.erb` looks like:

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>").prepend("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

How can I achieve what I want?

**Edit 1**

My bad, I wasn't fully clear with the original question.

I can't just use `.append`, due to the presence of a form field that is currently at the bottom of that list of children.

If I do use append, this is what the modified HTML looks like:

[image]

Note the `.row .question-46-new` appears before the last `.social-comment`.

So that ends up producing this:

[image: screenshot-of-rendered-comments]

Which is obviously what I don't want.

What I want is for the new comment to appear right above that `Write Comment` textbox, and at the end of the list of existing comments.

**Edit 2**

This is what my DOM tree looks like after attempting Pranav's suggestion:

[image]

**Edit 3**

After the latest attempt from Pranav, these are the results.

I tried this:

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>").children(".social-comment").last().after("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

That works well when there are existing comments, it just adds it to the last of the existing ones. When there are no existing comments though, the new comment just disappears.

Here is a picture of the DOM tree when there are no comments:

[image]

Here is a picture of the DOM tree after the comment has been added, using the above `.js.erb`:

[image]

No change. For what it's worth, I also tried it with the other suggestion:

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %> > .social-comment:last").after("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

And I get similar behavior. It works when there are existing comments, but doesn't work when there are none.

**Edit 4**

When I use the `:before` suggestion from Pranav, this is the result.

This is what my comment section looks like when I add one comment, when there was none before (notice the spacing is off and the alignment with the other DOM elements looks weird):

[image: not aligned going from 0 to 1 comment]

Then this is what it looks like when there is an existing comment (notice how weird the alignment looks):

[image: not aligned going from 1 to 2 comments]

But if I refresh, this is what it looks like (which is how it should look, but just not how it looks immediately after the comment is added):

[image: aligned on refresh]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead of **[`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** method.

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>").append("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Since you are updated the question, you can't do it using above code.  Instead what you can do is get the last `social-comment` element inside the div and then append it after the element. You can use **[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** to get the last one and **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** method to append after the last element.

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %> .social-comment:last").after("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Since there  is nested div with same class you need to get only direct children instead. So either use [child selector (`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %> > .social-comment:last").after("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

or use **[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)** and [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>").children(".social-comment").last().after("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

---

Also if the last div's class is always in format like  `parent id` followed by `-new`(eg: `question-36` and `question-36-new`) then you can done it using **[`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)** method.

```
$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>-new").before("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

Comment: This is a fair suggestion, but I wasn't clear in my original question. Please refresh the question to see what happens when I do this. In short, this can't work - for reasons I explain in the updated question.

Comment: I like the direction. For some reason though, it actually doesn't work. The comment just disappears. It is clear that it has submitted correctly, it just doesn't update the DOM correctly. Ideas?

Comment: @marcamillion : it'a bug from my side, that I missed `.` before the class selector.... Answer updated now.

Comment: Yeh I had tried that before and it didn't work. What is happening is it is still appending it after the textfield div. Check the question for an update on what the DOM looks like after this suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114996/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-marcamillion).

Comment: I have updated the question, and I left a comment in the chat room. Given that we aren't likely to be here together at the same time, I think it is best we chat here rather than the chatroom.

Comment: @marcamillion : did you tried `$(".question-<%= @comment.commentable.id %>-new").before("<%= j (render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");` ?

Comment: Yeh, I did before. But I just updated the question with screenshots of what happens when I use `.before`. That does work, it just doesn't fully align properly - which leads me to believe it isn't inserting the DOM in the exact place I would like it. Refresh the question to see what I mean.

Comment: Ok nevermind. I figured it out. All I had to do was add a `margin-top` to the comment text-field.